# Android app power consumption measurment

Tags: android, android-studio

How to check power consumption of each applications?

I've tried Android studio [batterystats](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html) and received a batterystats.txt 
.But the source itself pointed out that the category of Estimated power use(below is a part of it)

```
Estimated power use (mAh)
    Capacity: 2930, Computed drain: 43.9, actual drain: 58.6-87.9
    Screen: 35.6
    Unaccounted: 14.7 ( )
    Uid u0a2618: 2.91 ( cpu=2.17 wake=0.657 wifi=0.00656 sensor=0.0732 )
    Uid 0: 2.24 ( cpu=2.23 wake=0.0000336 wifi=0.00259 )
```

"is currently an extremely rough estimate and should not be considered experiment data."

I've seen a lot of applications which can measure the battery stats. But is there anyway to measure the battery stats by not using applications but other ways(using terminal window & command lines)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The battery historian is programmed in Python 2.7. You can use a command line to get batterystats.txt

The source code is available here

https://github.com/google/battery-historian